# How to convert string param to date var in HP-UX?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh, hp-ux

How to convert string param to date var in Hewlett-Packard UNIX (HP-UX)?

```
date -d
date: illegal option -- d
```

Can not use -d

I need the following:

```
the_date=`date`
date_in_seconds=$($the_date+"%s")
```

Any insight?

Comment: Can you clarify for me - are you looking for a way to get the date in seconds since epoch on HP-UX or something else entirely? (I answered the former below).

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=getting+seconds+since+epoch+hp-ux&oq=getting+seconds+since+epoch+hp-ux&aqs=chrome..69i57.5637j1j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) I see that it is a relatively common question that has a two main answers:

1. [Install GNU date](http://www.unix.com/302180604-post7.html?s=3e14737afa3d5577e264034415734cc5)
2. `perl -e 'print time(), "\n"'` ([several](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/HP-UX-Admin/2006-10/msg00016.html) [references](http://www.unix.com/302099671-post7.html) amongst others)

EDIT: although I worry I've misunderstood your question...